# Interacting with Siebel

Tags: siebel

I'm trying to interact with the Siebel Communications activex web application.We have an existing web app that needs to interact with elemets in the siebel activex's

Trying to add the Siebel app in an iframe is not effective,I can't script that iframe,it's on a different doamain.

The approach I'm considering : 
 Wrtitng another activex with a web browser control to load the siebel app.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a COM interface to support client-side integration with Siebel.  In order to use it, the EnableWebClientAutomation parameter needs to be set to TRUE in the application configuration file.  Setting that parameter makes sure the Siebel desktop integration object (ActiveX control) gets downloaded to your client machines.

```
[SWE]
EnableWebClientAutomation = TRUE
```

I don't have any experience in doing this type of integration, and there's not a whole lot of info in Siebel Bookshelf about it, but I'm pretty sure this is how Mercury LoadRunner integrates with Siebel for automated load testing.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can interact with the Active X control directly - you probably have to go direct to the Siebel application via a Siebel Business Server, and control the action from there.

The standard way to interact with Siebel from a desktop application is through the Siebel web client automation server - lots more info here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31104_02/books/OIRef/OIRefProgramming21.html#wp1004834

- B

Answer (score 0):

Active X is a dead component after IE 8.0. I would not suggest this. Elements of ActiveX is not open to public. these are stored under Siebsrvr\webtempl folder. these basically provides option to use HighInteractive Client. after OpenUI has come, these are obsolete to be used